# nHibernate Dynamic Query With OR

Tags: java, nhibernate, dynamic, hibernate-criteria

We have a form which allows users to specify criteria to query a database.

Our form builds "criterion" objects which are then used to build the nHibernate criteria.

Our current code to do this is:

```
public virtual ICriteria BuildCriteria(ICriteria criteria)
{
    foreach (SheCriterion criterion in this.SheCriterions)
    {
        if (criterion.OperatorKey == "OR")
        {
            //// code required here to process ORs
        }
        criteria.Add(criterion.BuildCriterion());
    }
    return criteria;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck - if we AND each criterion there is no problem but I'm having difficulties in working out how to add ORs - by the time we know that an OR is involved, the previous criterion has already been processed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is not that easy. Consider `a and b or c` there are 2 different possibilities `(a and b) or c` and `a and (b or c)` so if `a = false` you'll get two different answers. You'll have to build a tree of criterias and in

```
public virtual ICriteria BuildCriteria(ICriteria criteria)
{
    foreach (SheCriterion criterion in this.SheCriterions)
    {
        criteria.Add(criterion.BuildCriterion());
    }

    return criteria;
}

public virtual ICriterion BuildCriterion()
{
    if (OperatorKey == "OR")
    {
        return new Disjunction()
            .Add(Left.BuildCriterion())
            .Add(right.BuildCriterion());
    }
    else
    {
        return new Conjunction()
            .Add(Left.BuildCriterion())
            .Add(right.BuildCriterion());
    }
}
```

Update: you'll need a tree otherwise

```
Man { Name = "Bill", Eyecolor = "blue", Height = 175, IsRich = true };

// will show Bill
SELECT * FROM Men WHERE height > 180 AND eyecolor = blue OR IsRich = 1
SELECT * FROM Men WHERE (height > 180 AND eyecolor = blue) OR IsRich = 1

// will not show Bill
SELECT * FROM Men WHERE height > 180 AND (eyecolor = blue OR IsRich = 1)
```

Comment: Hi Firo, - I can't get this code to work - what are Left and right here?

Comment: your SheCriterions have to be a tree of criterias not a list of criterias. To illustrate i introduced an imaginary SheOrCriterion which has a left SheCriterion and a right SheCriterion. Other than that you (and NHibernate) won't be able to know where to put the brackets in the resulting filter

Comment: Thanks for your help so far - I'm having difficulty with the tree structure.  A search here shows that there aren't any standard tree structures in c#.

Comment: a tree structure is datastructure pattern which is used in a lot of places but is unique for each use case hence you have to build one yourself. Or you could make the UI simpler to only allow top level Or. Then you can still have a list of criterions where some of them are Orcriterions with a list of criterions, effectivly this is building a tree with a depth of 1